# How to setup virtual environment inside github desktop?

Tags: django, github, pre-commit-hook, github-desktop

We recently started use github-pre-commits for django project since then I am not able to commit changes using github desktop. I have activate my virtual env and use terminal only for commiting changes

can i make any changes which would let me commit changes from github desktop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no one-size-fits-all answer to this question, as the best way to set up a virtual environment inside GitHub Desktop will vary depending on your specific needs and preferences. However, some tips on how to set up a virtual environment inside GitHub Desktop include creating a new repository for your virtual environment, using a tool like Vagrant to manage your virtual environment, and using a GitHub-provided template to set up your virtual environment.